# With neo4j how to return the parents of each node as an array as part of the result

Tags: neo4j

I have the following query that returns about 6000 nodes:

```
MATCH (:Term {ontology_id:"CO_330"})<-[*]-(op:Term) RETURN op
```

It basically returns all the nodes for ontology CO_330. Each node has also a property called term_id which is unique. Nodes are related to each other in different ways through term_id.

How can I include in the result of my query for each node an array of the IDs of its direct parents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ids of the `Term`s with an incoming relationship to the "CO_330" `Term`(s):

```
MATCH (t:Term {ontology_id:"CO_330"})<--(op:Term)
RETURN t, COLLECT(op.term_id) AS parentIds
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct parents could be added with a construct similar to this

```
RETURN op,
[(op)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(n) | n.term_id] AS arrayOfIds
```